# Kubernetes Readiness probe failed error

Tags: docker, minikube, kubernetes-helm

While running my container on `kubernetes` using helm upgrade command, I am getting this error:

> 'Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.6:3003/: dial tcp
>   172.17.0.6:3003: getsockopt: connection refused'.

My docker image is for a node.js application and I am trying to manage it through minikube.

Comment: `readinessProbe` failure - k8s will not route traffic to pod;   `livenessProbe` failure - k8s will restart the pod.  Some useful notes: https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/notes-on-kubernetes-production-best-practices

Answer (score 39):

For anyone else here, if using helm to manage your deployments, you need to set `initialDelaySeconds` it in the `deployments.yaml` template in the `/templates` folder under `livenessProbe`. The `livenessProbe` will force restart your pod if the probe cannot connect, as was happening with mine. It wasn't giving my application enough time to build.

Comment: What is the value of initialDelaySeconds to be set?

Comment: An integer, like `initialDelaySeconds: 5`. This integer specify the nummer of seconds

Answer (score 13):

This could be solved by increasing the initial delay in the readiness check. Actually since the connection to the DB was taking more then the initial delay as a result of which the readiness probe was failing.

Comment: i increased from 15 seconds to 60 seconds but still it is getting failed. please share your inputs?

Comment: How you got rid of this?

Answer (score 11):

Helm:

I would recommend setting the `initialDelaySeconds` value in the `values.yaml` file
and use an action `{{ .Values.initialDelaySeconds }}` to insert the value into the `deployment.yaml` template.

kubectl:

Just add the `initialDelaySeconds: 5` if you want 5 seconds to your (deployment,pod,replicate set etc) manifest and apply your changes.

If it fails, get coffee and start looking at logs from the container

`kubectl logs -h` for more help

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue too. It was fixed by specifying that my docker image listen on host `0.0.0.0` with the command set in my dockerfile: `ENV HOST '0.0.0.0'`.

When deploying to a Docker, and potentially other, containers, it is advisable to listen on 0.0.0.0 because they do not default to exposing mapped ports to localhost.

Comment: why will this resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Helm & NodeJs :

For my Node.js app, 5s of [`initialDelaySeconds`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) wasn't the exact solution.

I solved the issue by using this [health-connect library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cloudnative/health-connect) from @cloudnative.

Just follow the instruction (README) to put some code importing the package and setting the app to respond to the `liveness` and `readiness` check request.

And make sure you write the correct `path` and `port` for both `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` in `/templates` - `deployment.yaml`.

```
  livenessProbe:
     initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.initialDelaySeconds }}
     httpGet:
       path: /live
       port: 3000
  readinessProbe:
     initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.initialDelaySeconds }}
     httpGet:
       path: /ready
       port: 3000
```

reference: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/health-checking-kubernetes-nodejs-application/

Answer (score 3):

Update coredns image from v1.5.0 to current version v1.6.9, then the error got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a .NET 6 Web API and the solution was updating docker base image in Dockerfile as below;

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
```

to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
```

Also, if you deploy your application with helm, it is better to make sure exposed application ports in docker compose file match the application's own ports.

Answer (score 1):

This error is mainly because the `initialDelaySeconds` paramater is set low. Increasing the time duration for the this parameter in the `deployment.yml` file like from `60` seconds to `180` seconds will resolve the issue. Given below is a sample configuration in the `deployment.yml`. As mentioned by @Chris in the above answer setting the initialDelaySeconds value in the `values.yaml` file and use an action `{{ .Values.initialDelaySeconds }}` to insert the value into the `deployment.yaml` template is a good practice.

```
  livenessProbe:
     httpGet:
       path: /live
       port: 8080
     timeoutSeconds: 5
     initialDelaySeconds: 60
     periodSeconds: 10
  readinessProbe:
     httpGet:
       path: /ready
       port: 8080
     timeoutSeconds: 5
     initialDelaySeconds: 60
     periodSeconds: 10
```

Comment: This is actually worked for me, i just added      
timeoutSeconds: 5
initialDelaySeconds: 60
periodSeconds: 10
to my deployment.yml and redeployed.

Answer (score 0):

So for me it was actually checking the wrong port; that's why the connection refused. So make sure you check if this isn't the Readiness/liveliness probe is pointed to the right address.