# is there any way to resolve liveness probe failure issue in Kubernetes environment after upgrading to spring boot 3.0.0 from spring boot 2.7,7?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, migration, spring-boot-actuator

1. I have upgraded spring boot application from version 2.7.7 to 3.0.0.
2. After upgrading it is working fine on local machine and able to access all the actuator health endpoints.
3. But, after deploying the same code to Kubernetes cluster we are getting error as "Readiness probe failed.    404 not found".
4. It is not able to call health endpoints and giving 404 error.
5. From the pod logs we can see that application is started properly on port 8080.
6. Please refer following image for error.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAMHk.png)

We tried the same on local machine it is working fine.
We redeployed the previous build with old springboot version it is working fine.
We also tried deploying the jar in minikube environment it is working fine.We are expecting to resolve the readiness probe issue.

We are expecting to resolve this issue and start the app with springboot 3.0.0 in kubernetes environment.

Comment: Please post your deployment.yaml with the readinrssprobe.

Comment: See if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540929/kubernetes-readiness-probe-failed-error

Comment: You can try to remove the probes from your deployment manifests. That way - the pods will not be restarted by Kubernetes and you can calmly troubleshoot them on the cluster.

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml or gradle build?

Comment: Hi After upgrading spring from 2.7.7 to 3.0.1 we encounter the same kind of issue only on our k8s cluster.

All web endpoints (actuator and @RequestMapping) return 404 http code with the tomcat default web page as body.

If we switch from tomcat to undertow all works fine. It's really strange. And we are always searching why we run into this issue.

Comment: Hi we solved our problem by updating azure application insight java agent to 3.4.7

Comment: could you solve it? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: @FlorentAmaridon this actually solved our issue too. we updated from 3.4.0 to 3.4.10(latest) and it fixed 404 issue

Answer (score 0):

Verify you actuators didn't move to a different port. In v3 there is a configuration for management port where by default the actuators are served.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.kubernetes-probes

```
management.server.port
```

Also make sure they are enabled

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled
```