# Kubernetes liveness/readiness return 404 after migrating springboot to 3.0.2 from 2.7.4

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I recently upgrade my project spring boot version to 3.0.2 from 2.7.4, and now liveness and readiness probe is returning 404. It is happening to one app and not to other app even though I haven't changed anything. Here are some differences:

App that works with 3.0.2:

- Uses Netty
- Not exposing any endpoint
- in helm chart, it only has livenessProbe:
- don't have ingress.yml

App that doesn't work:

- Uses Tomcat
- Exposes endpoint
- in helm, it has livenessProbe: and readinessProbe
- has ingress.yml

I removed ingress related yml files and deployed and still failed.

I tried deploy app without readinessProbe, and it deploys but if I port-forward and access liveness endpoint, it gives me 404 as well.

Here is helm.yml:

```
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 60
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 3
...
...
            - name: management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled
              value: 'true'
            - name: management.endpoint.health.show-details
              value: 'always'
```

We have three engineers trying to figure this out, but no luck so far. If you need any other information, please let me know.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74960530/is-there-any-way-to-resolve-liveness-probe-failure-issue-in-kubernetes-environme

Comment: Yup. it was app insight java agent issue

Comment: It took us few hours to figure it out, but it was App insight java agent version issue. We had 3.4.0, and it works when we updated to 3.4.10 (latest at the moment). We don't know why. As mentioned by @Rakesh Gupta, we found the answer in the comment section of this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74960530/is-there-any-way-to-resolve-liveness-probe-failure-issue-in-kubernetes-environme